# Real Time Video Application with VLC

Tags: flutter, video-streaming, cross-platform, vlc

For my simple real time video application I have to connect a camera with the device over **rtsp**. Now I am struggling with the 'real time' part there is always a delay over about 2 seconds, no matter which options I choose.

This is all I have found:

```dart
VlcPlayerController _vlcViewController = new VlcPlayerController.network(
    "rtsp://192.72.1.1/liveRTSP/av4",
    autoPlay: true,
    options: VlcPlayerOptions(
      advanced: VlcAdvancedOptions([
        VlcAdvancedOptions.clockJitter(300),
        VlcAdvancedOptions.clockSynchronization(0),
        VlcAdvancedOptions.fileCaching(300),
        VlcAdvancedOptions.liveCaching(130),
        VlcAdvancedOptions.networkCaching(300),
      ]),
      rtp: VlcRtpOptions([
        VlcRtpOptions.rtpOverRtsp(false),
      ]),
      sout: VlcStreamOutputOptions([
        VlcStreamOutputOptions.soutMuxCaching(300),
      ]),
      video: VlcVideoOptions([
        VlcVideoOptions.dropLateFrames(true),
        VlcVideoOptions.skipFrames(true),
      ]),
    ),
  );
```

Comment: I think the delay doesn't arise from the playback. My guess is, that the streaming and encoding itdelf might cause the delay. Also I think RTSP itself has a slight latency that might add up.

Comment: Do you think there is a better way how to reduce the delay? I can not change the settings of the camera itself

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I'm experiencing the same issue.